# Help with PayPal IPN

Tags: civievent, ipn

Sometime, I think in May, our PayPal IPN communication broke. We haven't had a lot of PayPal use since then, so I haven't discovered it until recently. I'm having a lot of trouble straightening it out.

I've gone back over the troubleshooting ideas [here](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/PayPal+Website+Payments+Standard+and+Recurring+Contributions). But still no luck.

That did help me narrow it down. I know this:

- PayPal sends the IPN.
- Civi logs the IPN in the Civicrm_system_log table, and I can't see anything strange about it, but I'm not sure what it's supposed to be. Here's the text

{"reset":"1","contactID":"4280","contributionID":"8377","module":"event","eventID":"33","participantID":"851","mc_gross":"900.00","invoice":"414ae4f493f47e11619bf7efc10b9f7b","protection_eligibility":"Ineligible","payer_id":"XSJW7PJ3W2WTE","tax":"0.00","payment_date":"16:59:26 Sep 14, 2016 PDT","payment_status":"Completed","charset":"windows-1252","first_name":"Ed","mc_fee":"20.10","notify_version":"3.8","custom":"","payer_status":"unverified","business":"office@MYDOMAIN.org","quantity":"1","verify_sign":"Adbt8gdfutr1Z-T39jfFAojvxDVnASV9dlQzsWCS5U9rO.yPNTzpJ.RF","payer_email":"him@hisDOMAIN.com","contact_phone":"xxxxxxxxx","txn_id":"77F61134Y5474453P","payment_type":"instant","last_name":"xxxx","receiver_email":"xxxxxxxxx","payment_fee":"20.10","receiver_id":"VLKFZ88QB68QL","txn_type":"web_accept","item_name":"4280-8377-Wine for Water","mc_currency":"USD","item_number":"","residence_country":"US","receipt_id":"2531-4793-0283-6721","handling_amount":"0.00","transaction_subject":"","payment_gross":"900.00","shipping":"0.00","ipn_track_id":"d48d1e5a8c3da"}

- the IPN doesn't update the payment from Pending to Completed. The really bad thing is that event registrants don't end up getting their proper email confirmation.

What are some next steps to get to the bottom of this?

Joomla 3.6, Civi 4.7.11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a pending/completed issue recently resolved in  v 4.7.12 - link to JIRA ticket is: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18483

Hope this helps,
Tamar

Comment: Thank, Tamar. I followed through to both https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/8270/files and https://gist.github.com/monishdeb/0deb5d947fe207b1f72e206ba42458e8 and applied the patches (the first was already applied - I'm using 4.7.11). Didn't help, and I'm very sad.

Comment: As the saying goes, uy gevalt! Perhaps there were other changes made in 4.7.12 that makes it work? I know there was a lot of back and forth on that one - perhaps a comment to Monish Deb via the JIRA ticket to confirm? Or, perhaps it is an entirely different issue? Bummer.

Comment: The above JIRA ticket was actually not working for Joomla a month ago, but it has since been reopened, fixed, and is expected to be in 4.7.13.

Comment: Yay - glad to hear it - lots of hard work put into that one!